# Operating system that does nothing but display an image?

Tags: linux, windows, display

I am looking for an operating system or some other sort of solution that will allow the computer to do nothing but display a static image indefinitely. This going to be used on a monitor that is going to display the company directory in our lobby. I just need a simple way to show the image indefinitely.

Comment: Use a Linux distribution, they're free.

Comment: Serious question, why couldn't you just print out this image and post it in the lobby?

Comment: @Jake I also recommend either a basic Linux distribution, or just install windows and put some fullscreen image viewer program in the startup folder; it doesn't really sound like it matters if it takes a few extra seconds to start up, as long as the image stays there. You don't really need a crazy custom solution unless you have a specific requirement for instant display after power on.

Comment: You might also want to consider something like @ChrisInEdmonton says; maybe just print it on a transparency with a light box behind it.

Comment: (Or, going back to Linux land, if you want something more self-contained, a basic full-screen imageviewer on startup on a Beagle Board (http://beagleboard.org/Products/BeagleBoard) connected to a monitor is a small, cheap, low power and easy-to-setup option).

Comment: I think the keyword you are looking for is _digital signage_. Combine your search with _Raspberry Pi_, and you will find some cheap solutions. Keep in mind that also with modern LCD screens, you will get a burn-in effect if the image stays the same for a long time.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Digital-Frames-Picture-Frame/b?node=525460

Comment: Many TVs will accept images on a USB drive, and will display one image or a slide show.  No need for a computer.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the suggestion to use Linux, the simplest method might be to take an old XP desktop, load up Picasa or some other image viewing tool, and have it display the desired image fullscreen. This also offers the flexibility of displaying a slideshow, or playing a video, if you decide to change it in the future, plus the benefit of requiring little setup or additional technical know-how.

Answer (score 0):

Get an old or broken monitor and then go to a sign printer and get the image printed in vinyl film the exact size of the monitor and have him stick the film on the display face.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP is looking for an **OS** to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Get a computer that is close by, and always on. Set it up with a video card that can send output to two monitors, and get a longer VGA/DVI/HDMI cable (depending on the card and monitor) to connect it with. Then, load up the picture on the screen, and ignore it, while you work on the other monitor.